# Flyway with Spanner

Tags: flyway, google-cloud-spanner

https://www.googlecloudspanner.com/2018/01/google-cloud-spanner-with-flyway.html?showComment=1552920901424#c4014111284657409891

I am trying to get spanner working with flyway using this article. There is no clear tutorial and I am a beginner to all of this, how can I set up spanner to work with spanner. Are there any video tutorials?

Answer (score 2):

The Spanner support pull request has not yet been merged into Flyway, so you will have to work with your own custom build of Flyway in order to use it with Cloud Spanner at this moment. You can achieve this by following these steps:

1) Clone the fork containing the Flyway support using the following command:

`git clone git@github.com:olavloite/flyway.git`

2) Either build and install this into your own Maven repository, or import the Maven project into your development workspace.

Building and storing it in your local Maven repository is achieved by running the following command in the root folder of the Flyway project that you cloned in step 1:

`mvn install`

How to import the project into your workspace depends on your IDE. If you are using Eclipse, you should use the option File | Import -> Maven | Existing Maven Projects and then select the root folder of the project from step 1.

3) Add the following to the  part of the pom.xml of *your* project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>nl.topicus</groupId>
    <artifactId>spanner-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>0-SNAPSHOT</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
</dependency>
```

You should now be able to use Flyway with Cloud Spanner in your project.

There is also a working example project that you could clone here: https://github.com/olavloite/spanner-flyway-example

Note that this example project will also require that you follow steps 1 and 2 above in order to get the custom build of Flyway that includes the Cloud Spanner support.

Comment: So I've tried to download and run the sample example and got this when I did mvn install and got this error:
Failed to execute goal on project spanner-flyway-example: Could not resolve dependencies for project nl.topicus:spanner-flyway-example:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:0-SNAPSHOT

Could you help me understand what Im doing wrong, Im sure its more simple than I think..

Comment: I am also getting this warning, possibly an issue as well: 
The POM for org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

Just need some guidance as to what I should do, thanks!

Comment: You should clone the olavloite/flyway.git repository and run `mvn install` in the root directory of that repository, and not of the example project. If you run `mvn install` in root directory of the sample project, without having also cloned the olavloite/flyway.git repository as described in step 1, you will get the error message you are describing.